# Measuring the scaling behaviour of multithreaded applications

Tags: multithreading, performance, optimization, scaling, measurement

I am working on an application which supports **many-core MIMD architectures** (on consumer/desk-computers). I am currently worrying about the **scaling behaviour** of the application. Its designed to be massively parallel and addressing **next-gen** hardware. That's actually my problem. Does anyone know any software to **simulate/emulate many-core MIMD Processors** with >16 cores on a machine-code level? I've already implemented a software based thread sheduler with the ability to simulate multiple processors, by simple timing techniques.
I was curious if there's any software which could do this kind of simulation on a lower level preferably on an assembly language level to get better results. I want to emphasize once again that I'm only interested in MIMD Architectures. I know about OpenCL/CUDA/GPGPU but thats not what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will rarely find all-purpose testing tools that are ALSO able to target very narrow (high-performance) corners - for a simple reason: the overhead of the "general-purpose" object will defeat that goal in the first place.

This is especially true with paralelism where locality and scheduling have a huge impact.

All this to say that I am affraid that you will have to write your own testing tool to target your exact usage pattern.

That's the price to pay for relevance.

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing your application in C/C++, I might be able to help you out.

[My company](http://www.vectorfabrics.com/) has created a tool that will take any C or C++ code and simulate its run-time behavior at bytecode level to find parallelization opportunities. The tool highlights parallelization opportunities and shows how parallel tasks behave.
The only mismatch is that our tool will also provide refactoring recipes to actually get to parallelization, whereas it sounds like you already have that.